# Groovy in SoapUI: how to create Date always from working day? (Monday -Friday)

Tags: date, groovy, soapui

*Hi, for a regression test in SoapUI I need to paste groovy script (as test properties), which would provide date of working day - any future day Monday - Friday in format "RRRR-MM-DD"*
Any hint?

I unsuccessfully tried a script:

```
${=def now = new Date();Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();c1.setTime(now);for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);}now = c1.getTime()now.format("yyyy-MM-dd");}
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this script isn't working? And you just need "any future working day in the foreseeable future"?

Comment: yes, I need just "any working day in future" - the soones from Today if Today is not working day.

Answer (score 1):

This script should give you the first coming monday. If you run the script on a monday, you will get the next monday.

```
Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance()
c1.setTime(new Date()+1)
while (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)!=Calendar.MONDAY) {
    c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
}
return c1.getTime().format("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: excellent, it worked as I needed :). getting always future Monday. Thank you very much, Steen !

Comment: I have idea to upgrade the script:
NOW:
It search first future Monday

UPGRADE:
How to search first future Monday-Friday?

Comment: Calendar c1 = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(new Date());
c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SATURDAY) c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
if (c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY)c1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
return c1.getTime().format("yyyy-MM-dd");